# How to use properly INSERT INTO SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert records from other tables into store_orders_items. 
For example:

```
INSERT INTO store_orders_items( order_id, sel_item_id, sel_item_price)
  SELECT order_id, sel_item_id, sel_item_price
      FROM orders_ids 
      INNER JOIN store_orders ON store_orders.id = orders_ids.order_id
      INNER JOIN store_shoppertrack ON  store_items.id=store_shoppertrack.sel_item_id
      Where session_id = '".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]."';
```

Then I received the following message: Unknown column 'sel_item_price' in 'field list'. I tried to set sel_item_price As item_price to no avail.
Here are my tables:

#### store_orders_items:

```
id| order_id | sel_item_id |sel_item_price|  
-------------------------------------------        
  |          |             |              |
```

#### store_shoppertrack:

```
id| session_id | sel_item_id |date_added|  
-------------------------------------------        
  |            |             |          |
```

store_orders:

```
id| item_total| order_date| 
---------------------------       
  |            |          |
```

#### store_items:

```
id| item_price| item_color|  
---------------------------       
  |           |           |
```

#### orders_ids:

```
id| order_id | status|  
----------------------       
  |          |       |
```

Comment: you dont have sel_item_price is any tables you are joining on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no table in jour join which has either a column named `sel_item_price`, nor a column `item_price`. The `INSERT INTO` has nothing to do with this, the `SELECT` on its own will fail just as well. I assume that you wanted to join with the `store_items` table as well, and select the `item_price` column from that table for insertion into the `sel_item_price` table of `store_order_items`. You could rewrite your `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT order_id, store_shoppertrack.sel_item_id, store_items.item_price AS sel_item_price
  FROM orders_ids 
  INNER JOIN store_orders ON store_orders.id = orders_ids.order_id
  INNER JOIN store_items ON store_items.id = store_orders.sel_item_id
  INNER JOIN store_shoppertrack ON  store_items.id=store_shoppertrack.sel_item_id
  Where session_id = 'foo';
```

The `AS sel_item_price` is optional, since you already specified the destination column in the `INSERT INTO` part. But it might help consistency, as the output of the `SELECT` will now hace volumns labeled the same as those of the target table. And it exhibits that you got the order of the `AS` wrong in your question, so you might learn something here.

I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1bbb4/6) for your schema and query.

Comment: Even though I removed sel_item_id from store_orders, your explanation was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

The field `sel_item_price` is only in your `store_orders_items` table which is not part of your select query. This is the cause of the error you listed.

Comment: I see it in `store_orders` too.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - `sel_item_id != sel_item_price`... look again.

Comment: expanding on this, maybe he wants to do "item_price as sel_item_price"

Comment: @StephenGarle - Maybe, I'm not a huge fan of guessing. With my answer at least he has the information he needs to fix his error. No need to spoon-feed :)

Comment: "The sel_item_price field is included here, as opposed to simply relating to the item record (item_price) because you might have occasion to change the pricing in your item record." (PHP, MYSQL and Apache All in one, Julie Meloni)

Comment: @AH - ...What? `sel_item_price` is not in any of the tables used in the select query... it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this tables the only field `sel_item_price` is in the table `store_orders_items` which is the one you are going to insert the data. Thats why you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be, you are using `store_items` alias but it is not in your join

```
INSERT INTO store_orders_items( order_id, sel_item_id, sel_item_price)
  SELECT order_id, sel_item_id, sel_item_price
      FROM orders_ids 
      INNER JOIN store_orders ON store_orders.id = orders_ids.order_id
      INNER JOIN store_order_items 
                  ON store_orders.id = store_order_items.order_id --missing
      INNER JOIN store_shoppertrack 
                  ON store_items.id=store_shoppertrack.sel_item_id
      Where session_id = '".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]."';
```

Comment: Unknown column 'store_orders.sel_item_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Updated query again check now

Comment: I'm sorry. Store_orders table is not supposed to have a sel_item_id column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also join against `store_items`, and include the column `item_price` from this table in your `SELECT`, not `store_item_price` which only exists in the table you are inserting into